# Mysql - Inserção com Palavra de Passe Gerada à parte

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, node.js

Eu estou a tentar fazer a inserção de Clientes mas com uma palavra passe que é gerada por um código mas não tenho bem a certeza de como implementar o uso desta.

```
site.get("/processa_InsereCliente", function (req, res) {

    // verificação se todos os atributos necessários foram preenchidos no formulário anterior
    if (req.query.Nome_cliente && req.query.Morada_cliente && req.query.CP_cliente && req.query.Localidade_cliente && req.query.Telefone_cliente && req.query.Email_cliente && req.query.Profissao_cliente && req.query.NIF_cliente) {
        var query = "INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES(null," + mysql.escape(req.query.Nome_cliente) + ',' + 

            mysql.escape(req.query.Password_cliente) + 

            "," + mysql.escape(req.query.Morada_cliente) + "," + mysql.escape(req.query.CP_cliente) + "," + mysql.escape(req.query.Localidade_cliente) +
            "," + mysql.escape(req.query.Telefone_cliente) +
            "," + mysql.escape(req.query.Profissao_cliente) +
            "," + mysql.escape(req.query.Dn_cliente) +
            "," + mysql.escape(req.query.NIF_cliente) + ")";
        runQuery(query, function (result) {

            if (result && result.affectedRows > 0) {
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                res.redirect('/Assinatura')
            }

        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/')
    }
});
```

A página que insere os clientes vai buscar os dados a um formulário de outra página, sendo que essa parte funciona, mas a parte do  mysql.escape(req.query.Password_cliente) queria que fosse substituido pela variavel gerada pelo seguinte código:

```
  <script>
        function generatePassword() {
            var length = 8,
                charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
                Password = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
                Password += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
            }
            alert(Password);
        }

    </script>
```

Não sei se estou a fazer das melhores das formas ou sequer da correta, mas até agora não consegui encontrar semelhante para me ajudar a resolver este problema.

Agradeço por toda ajuda!!

Comment: E o que fazes com o valor de `Password_cliente`? não usas e crias somente uma password sem relação com o que o cliente inseriu?

Comment: O que eu iria fazer era criar uma password aleatória que vai para a base de dados, mas que depois o nome de usuario e a palavra passe são entregues ao usuario através de pdf. Eu não tenho um campo para a inserção de password por parte do usuario.

Comment: Ok! Então basta ter `mysql.escape(generatePassword())` em vez de `mysql.escape(req.query.Password_cliente)` certo?